# Paypal recurring billing

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to create a billing a request that will re-occur every week in my php application. I'm able to create a billing however i see that my subscription doesnt get executed as infinite. After first week, it terminates. I want to arrange it in a way that it should re-occur every week. With below code, I'm able to create a subscription; but when i check from paypal sandbox, it only stays for one week although i set the total cycles to 0, which is infinite mode. Also, i tried to change the interval_unit -> "DAY" instead of "WEEK" but i see that it is also not getting set.

```
 public function createNewPlan($name, $description, $amount)
{

    if (strlen($this->productId) > 0) {
        $header = array();
        $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
        $header[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->token . '';
        $url = $this->apiUrl . '/v1/billing/plans';
        $data = '
   {
      "product_id": "' . $this->productId . '",
      "name": "' . $name . '",
      "description": "' . $description . '",
      "type: INFINITE",
      "billing_cycles": [
        {
          "frequency": {
            "interval_unit": "WEEK",
            "interval_count": 1
          },
          "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
          "sequence": 1,
          "total_cycles": 0,
          "pricing_scheme": {
            "fixed_price": {
              "value": "' . $amount . '",
              "currency_code": "EUR"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "payment_preferences": {
        "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
        "setup_fee": {
          "value": "0",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        },
        "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE",
        "payment_failure_threshold": 2
      }
   }
';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($err) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($errmsg) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $json = json_decode($result);
            return $json->id;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But it really must be documented in the PayPal user docs

Comment: interval count is used for how many times the charging should happen. for example in the above code it means, charge the user 1 time per week. and the bottom, total cycle is how many  times should be the total charging. if its 10, total of 10 charges will occur. and if its 0, it means its infinite number of membership. so this is how it is from documentation but somehow doesn't work :/